# how to put the given java code on the button "b1".So that when it is pressed the code runs

Tags: java, html

```
  <%@page language="java" contentType="text/html" import="java.sql.*" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html> 
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form> 
        <table width="300">
            <tr>
                <td>Enter User Name:<td><input type="text" name="uname">
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Password:
                <td><input type="password" name="pass"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button  name="b1" >Save</button>
                <td><input type="reset" name="rs" value="Reset"></td>
        </table>
    </form> 

    <%
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/projectjsp", "root", "");
        Statement s = con.createStatement();
        String a = request.getParameter("uname");
        String b = request.getParameter("pass");
        String q = "insert into userlogin (username,password) values ('" + a + "','" + b + "')";
        s.execute(q);
        out.print(q);

    %>  

</body>
</html>
```

When it is opened in web browser its shows the error and exception

> javax.servlet.ServletException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'null' for key 'PRIMARY'

and when the code is removed the page displays fine.

Comment: Well, it does say there is a duplicate entry 'null' for key 'PRIMARY', so have you tried fixing that error?

Comment: Note that the way you're building the SQL is horribly insecure. Use prepared statements instead. Additionally, try not to mix your presentation logic and business logic. Finally, what does this have to do with PHP?